# AMQP basic.get concurrent consumers pulling from Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

When using RabbitMQ as Message Broker, I have a scenario where multiple concurrent consumers pull messages from a Queue using the basic.get AMQP method and use explicit acknowledgement for deleting the message from the Queue. Assuming the following setup

Q has messages M1, M2, M3 and has consumers C1, C2 and C3 (each having its own connection and channel) connected to it.

1. How is concurrency handled in the basic.get method? Is the call to basic.get method synchronized to handle concurrent consumers each using its own connection and channel? C1, C2 and C3 issue a basic.get call to receive a message at the same time (assume the server receives all 3 requests simultaneously).
2. C1 requests a message using basic.get and gets M1. When C2 requests for a message, since its using a different connection, does it get M1 again?
3. How can consumers pull messages in batches of a predefined size?

Comment: It's not clear what is your question about.

Comment: The second point is NO. The other points I don't understand! What do you mean for "synchronized to handle concurrent consumers"! RMQ is a FIFO system, so you put 3 messages and the C1 get the first, C2 the seconds.. etc... Assuming you are using prefetch = 1.

Comment: Did my answer below help? If so, please mark it as the answer. If not, how can I elaborate?

Answer (score 12):

Your questions really hit at the heart of queuing and process theory, so I will answer from that standpoint (RabbitMQ is really a generic message broker as far as my answers are concerned, as this applies to any message broker).

> How is concurrency handled in the basic.get method? Is the call to
>   basic.get method synchronized to handle concurrent consumers each
>   using its own connection and channel? C1, C2 and C3 issue a basic.get
>   call to receive a message at the same time (assume the server receives
>   all 3 requests simultaneously).

**Answer 1**: RabbitMQ is designed to be a reliable message broker. It contains internal processes and controls to ensure that the same message does not get passed out multiple times to different consumers.  Now, due to the impracticality of testing the scenario that you describe, does it work perfectly? Who knows. That is why properly-designed applications using message-based architecture will use idempotent transactions, such that if the same transaction is processed multiple times, the result will be the same as if the transaction was processed once.
**Takeaway**: Design your application so that the answer to this question is unimportant.

> C1 requests a message using basic.get and gets M1. When C2 requests
>   for a message, since its using a different connection, does it get M1
>   again?

**Answer 2**: No. Subject to the assumptions of my previous answer, the RabbitMQ broker will not serve the same message back once it has been delivered. Depending on the settings of the channel and queue, the message may be automatically acknowledged upon delivery and will never be redelivered. Other settings will have the message requeue automatically upon the "death" of the processing thread/channel or a negative acknowledgment from your processing thread.  This is important functionality, since a "poison" message could repeatedly wreak havoc in your application if it could be served up to multiple consumers. **Takeaway**: you may safely rely on this assumption in designing your application.

> How can consumers pull messages in batches of a predefined size?

**Answer**: They can't, nor would it make sense for them to. In any queuing system, the fundamental assumption is that items are removed from the queue in single file. Attempts to violate this assumption result in unpredictable behavior; furthermore, single-piece flow is commonly the most efficient method of processing.  However, in the real world, there are cases where batch sizes > 1 are necessary. In such cases, it makes sense to load the batch into its own single message, so this may require a separate processing thread that pulls messages from the queue and batches them together, or put them in batches initially.  Keep in mind that once you have multiple consumers, there is no possible way to guarantee single messages will be processed in order.  **Takeaway**: Batching should be avoided wherever possible, but where it is not practical to avoid, you may not assume that batches will contain individual messages in any particular order.

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna read the [RabbitMQ Api guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) and the [introduction to Amqp](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

First of all, avoid consuming messages using `basicGet` in your consumers. Rather use the Consumer interface `basicConsume`. This allows RabbitMq to push you messages as they arrive on the queue. Everything else is a waist of resources here as it boils down to busy polling.

When using `basicConsume` RabbitMq will even push you more messages in the background up to a certain `prefetch` count. This allows you to process multiple messages concurrently as well as minimizing the time you need to wait for your next message to process (if some message is available).

Concurrency is not an issue at all, that's what you're using a queue for!
When having multiple consumers on one queue, a message will always only be delivered to one consumer (as long as the message is ACKed). Otherwise you need private queues for each consumer and route your messages accordingly.

Btw, if you're able to share the connection among your consumers, you should do so.
Just make sure to use one channel per thread.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to use a pull method vs. a push method to retrieve messages.

Comment: Sure, there is good reasons for a pull method! I just wouldn't consider it the typical use case.

Comment: It really is a matter of program semantics, as the resultant behavior of the application is the same.

Comment: What are legitimate reasons to use a pull method vs. a push method? Everybody tells that's wrong and nobody tells when it's right.

Comment: From an architecture perspective, at least in the current version of RabbitMQ, the pull method is easier to implement. It's also less complicated, with fewer settings required. When a consumer is ready for a message, it gets a message. It also parallels the modern manufacturing systems theory, which emphasizes "pull" via [kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban).

Answer (score -1):

There is no special configuration required for that scenario. Each client will atomically fetch and receive one message from the queue, just as you would like to happen.

Comment: So, does RabbitMQ handle the synchronization part? Does it implement some locking on a basic.get request?

Comment: Rephrasing my question:  How is the synchronization on basic.get handled? Is there some locking on a basic.get request?